# Injecting DbContext into FileProvider in ASP.NET Core

Tags: razor, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to load some of the views from the database as described in [here](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location). So I want to use EF Core in the File provider.

`RazorViewEngineOptions` has a `FileProviders` property that you can add your file provider to. The problem is that you have to give it an instace of the file provider. So you'll need to instantiate all of the file providers' dependencies right there in Startup's `ConfigureServices` method.

Currently I inject an instance of `IServiceProvider` into the `Configure` method of Startup. Then I store the instance in a field (called `_serviceProvider`):

```
IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IServiceProvider provider)
{
   _serviceProvider = provider;
   ...
}
```

Then in `ConfigureServices` I use that field to instanciate the `UIDbContext`.

```
services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(options =>
{
    var fileProvider = new DbFileProvider(_serviceProvider.GetService<UIDbContext>());
    options.FileProviders.Add(fileProvider);
});
```

Is there any better way to be able to inject the `UIDbContext` into the `DbFileProvider` constructor Or any way to instantiate a `UIDbContext` inside `DbFileProvider` without `IServiceProvider`?

Comment: Even if you may not know it yet, but you **don't want** to use `DbContext` as a file provider source the way you did. `DbContext` **isn't thread-safe**, so it won't work when you have one single DbContext instance for the whole provider. You'd have to instantiate a connection (like in the linked article) or `DbContext` per `IFileInfo`/`IDirectoryContents ` instance

Comment: @Tseng You are right, I've already faced issues from that. But instantiating a new `UIDbContext` requires an instance of `DbContextOptions<UIDbContext>` How do you get hold of that without an `IServiceProvider` ? Is it a good idea to pass a reference of the `IServiceProvider` to `DbFileProvider` so that it uses it to resolve the `DbContextOptions<UIDbContext>`?

Comment: If I'm not completely wrong,  the `DbContextOptions<UIDbContext>` should be a singleton, so you can resolve it w/o any issues inside `Configure` and pass it to your provider. Alternatively you can also call construct `DbContextOptionsBuilder` and build a db context options, but then you have to repeat the configuration for you did inside `AddDbContext` (i.e. `.UseSqlServer()`). However it can be useful, as it allows you to set different settings (i.e. changing the way how includes, errors etc. are logged)

Comment: @Tseng I think your solution is very reasonable, can you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: And indeed it seems that DbContextOptions is registered as a singleton
https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2016/10/24/ef-core-1-1-creating-dbcontext-instances/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use `DbContext` as a file provider source the way you did.

`DbContext` **isn't thread-safe**, so it won't work when you have one single `DbContext` instance for the whole provider, because multiple requests could call the `DbContext` and it's operation more than once at the same time, resulting in exception when trying to execute 2 queries in parallel.

You'd have to instantiate a connection (like in the linked article) or `DbContext` per `IFileInfo`/`IDirectoryContents` instance.

`DbContextOptions<UIDbContext> should be registered as singleton, so you can resolve it once`inside Configure` w/o any issues and pass it to your provider.

Alternatively you can also call `DbContextOptionsBuilder` and build/construct a `DbContextOptions<T>`, but then you have to repeat the configuration for you did inside `AddDbContext` (i.e. `.UseSqlServer()`).

However it can be useful, as it allows you to set different settings (i.e. changing the way how includes, errors etc. are logged).